# in Python 3.6, how do I print a type of a variable without seeing the word 'class' in the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried this:

```
print(type(list(soup.children)[0]))
```

but the output I get includes the word 'class'
Output:
`[<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>]`

I'd like it to only show me 'bs4.element.Tag', just like if I wrote in the command line:

```
type(list(soup.children)[0])
```

Output:
`bs4.element.Tag`

Comment: @Aran-Fey: I think you accidentally edited out a part that wasn't displaying because it was in `<>`.

Comment: @user2357112 Oh, you're right. Thanks for the heads up.